# Prettier a flower

Tags: inversion, comparative

Is

> This one is *prettier a flower than a rose*.

acceptable?

Or am I not allowed to invert it and have to say

> This one is *a prettier flower than a rose*.

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *This one is prettier a flower than a rose.

This inversion is not grammatical or idiomatic.

Ordinarily—let's say in 999 cases out of 1000—determiners (Det) precede modifiers (Mod).

> ... <sub>Det</sub>**a** <sub>Mod</sub>**prettier** flower  ...

In fact, one widely accepted analysis of noun phrases (NP) understands the determiner as a complement not to the noun but to the 'nominal' phrase (Nom) composed of the noun and its dependent modifiers, like this:

[image: NP]

About the only situation I can think of where an adjective is permitted to precede a determiner is <s>a comparative construction</s> **when the adjective is** embedded in <s>another</s> **a** comparative construction.<sup>1</sup> In this example I've put the 'inside' comparative operators in boldface and the 'outside' comparative operators in bold italics:

> This is ***so much*** pretti**er** a flower **than** a rose ***that*** I will never grow roses again.

1. <sub>I've corrected this in light of Araucaria's answer [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73787/when-articles-are-placed-after-adjectives/73789#73789), which is a far superior explanation of how these constructions work.</sub>

This construction is acceptable in any register. Note, however, that there is a slightly more formal variant which eliminates the unusual Mod-Det-Noun sequence by postposing the modifying phrase—moving it to the right of the noun. (This is standard with any modifying phrase which has one or more constituents to the right of its own head.)

> This is a flower so much prettier than a rose that I will never grow roses again.

Comment: +1 (Prettier a flower you never did see.)

Comment: This post might be relevant for your answer:[When are adjectives placed before articles?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73787/when-articles-are-placed-after-adjectives/73789#73789)

Comment: @Araucaria I knew this had been addressed somewhere, but I couldn't think how to find it! Your answer is much more comprehensive; I had not considered *non*-comparatives within comparative constructions. I do think that the governing consideration with your 'adverbs of degree' is that they are constituents of comparative constructions, even if the comparison is not explicitly drawn--which I take it is what you mean by "this normally entails there being a Complement phrase which indicates the actual extent or degree involved".

Comment: I wrote that there answer for EL&U! I wish I knew if that's what I meant. I can't remember! I think I agree with you though.

Comment: I've been mulling over OP's example here, and I'm wondering if it's the overall meaning of the sentence that's the problem (This flower is too pretty to be a rose/prettier than roses are). If we modify the example a bit, it seems less wonky to me "This one is (much) prettier a flower than that one" doesn't sound too bad to me.  (But maybe it depends on how you squint at it ...) Hmmm ...

Comment: Because *much* is a determiner.

Comment: @LawrenceC I think not. In some contexts *much* may be a quantifier, which may act as a determiner or a fused-head NP (*Much remains to be done*); but in this context *much* is an adverb modifying *prettier*.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
This flower is prettier than a rose
```

The use of 'a flower' in both of your sentences is unnecessary regardless of the word order.

Comment: I'm aware of that, thanks for the answer, but I was just trying to learn about inversion. I will edit my sentence.

Comment: You can use both. The first one is more poetic than the second.

Answer (score 0):

"If an adjective is being modified by a deictic degree adverb such as so, too, as, this or that then the adjective and adverb must go before, not after, the indefinite article." - that's for "prettier a flower" explanation. Now you know what should be up front. Source: [When articles are placed after adjectives?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73787/when-articles-are-placed-after-adjectives)

As for inversion - you have to start over :) as in your sentence there is no inverted word order. There is though in Araucaria's.