# How could an adverb come straight after a transitive verb?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, transitivity

What I know, or what we have been taught is we could not put adverbs directly after a verb when the verb is transitive.

Could you tell me how is this possible if “had” is a transitive verb here in this example:

> - we *had* **quite** a nice weekend here.

Isn’t supposed to be like? :

- 1) We quite had a nice weekend here.

Or

- 2) We had a quite nice weekend here.

Comment: **quite** modifies the NP "a nice weekend here".  Your rule addresses situations like "He ran quickly the race" which is not idiomatic.

Comment: I got it here what I was looking for. You are right that quite modifies “ nice weekend here”. The reason, I think, quite is separated from the NP is “‘quite’is an adverb of degree” @Tᴚoɯɐuo  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73787/when-articles-are-placed-after-adjectives

Comment: We have the abstract set of {nice weekends}.   The degree exists among members of the set: they vary in their degree of niceness.  This weekend we had here was an instance member of the set (it was **a** nice weekend) and it was among the nicer ones of that set, being **quite a nice weekend**.

Comment: As nice weekends go, this one was rather a nice one.