# Grammatical error in using 'the' after an adjective

Tags: articles, definite-article, word-order, past-participles

In the sentence:

> "Please find attached the document containing the list of items."

Is the usage of "the" after "attached" forbidden by some rule of the English language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence is perfectly fine.

The following is also correct:

> Please find **the** attached <strike>the</strike> document containing the list of items.

There is not such rule, as you mention it. But there *are* rules about when and how to use the definite article ("the").

Comment: I thought so. However I had a difference of opinion with my colleague and that's why I asked. Thanks a lot for answering. Btw are you a native English speaker?

Comment: Not native, but very experienced.

Comment: Is 'attached' a verb or an adjective here?

Comment: In your example, "attached" is verb (past participle). In my example, it is adjective.

Comment: How do you know that in my example it's not an adjective? Is it because it's not immediately followed by a noun?

Comment: As explained here (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adjective), an adjective modifies a noun. In your example, "attached" modifies "find", which is a verb. Therefore it has to be either an adverb or another verb - and my assumption is that it is a past participle, since it is not defined as an adverb: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attached.

Comment: So it seems I had asked a wrong question(I had assumed 'attached' to be an adjective here). Can you give me examples where 'the' comes between a noun and an adjective?

Comment: That is quite strange. Why do you want specifically "the" between noun and adjective?

Comment: Because this is exactly what the objection of my colleague was. He seemed to think that 'attached' was an adjective here and that is why we can't put 'the' between it and the 'document'.

Comment: "the" is not **after** something, it is **before** a noun. There can be adjectives between "the" and the noun.

Comment: Yeah..so can you think of sentences having this structure in them

Comment: Adjective+the+noun

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/73787/69333 this might be relevant here but I couldn't find any example using 'the'.

Comment: those are very special constructs, they do not follow standard grammar rules.By that, I mean that they change the standard order of the words into something else. I am not aware of a way to do something similar with "the".

Answer (score 2):

"**Please find attached**" is basically a set phrase now in English. It can be analysed for parts of speech, certainly, but it is not thought of in such terms by native speakers. I'm not even sure of its origins, but you might think of it as a contraction of:

> Please find, attached to this email (or letter), ...

Thus any appropriate noun phrase can follow it - with an article or not.