# Sentences having the structure - adjective+'the'+noun

Tags: grammar

Is there any grammatically correct example where the structure mentioned in the title i.e. adjective immediately followed by 'the'+noun is used in a sentence? Does any rule prohibit such usage? 
This [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/73787/69333) explores a similar concept but I couldn't find any example using 'the'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example just came to my head:

> If you have a large family, the **bigger the car** is, the better.

But you have to be careful, these constructs are not the "mainstream" grammar rules - they are merely particular situations / constructs.